# How do I combine a link and image in ruby and rails using gem gravatar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, hyperlink, gravatar

I have a separate link and image

```
<li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path %><li>
<li><%= image_tag current_user.gravatar_url, style: "max-width: 100%;height:50px;display:inline-block;border-radius:75%;"%>
</li>
```

and I would like to combine them to one image link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine both "Log Out" text and image as a single link, then you can write your code in this format:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path do %>
    "Log Out"
    <%= image_tag current_user.gravatar_url, style: "max-width: 100%;height:50px;display:inline-block;border-radius:75%;"%>
  <% end %> 
</li>
```